# Select sum of each

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a Table like this in MySQL

```
 1. ID, (int, autoincrement, primary)
 2. Date (timestamp)
 3. Device (int)
 4. Text (text)
```

For a Report, i want to find out, how many records for each type of device there is.
Like "Device '5' = 100 rows".

Can this be done by a pure sql comand, or do i have to loop through all types of device's by php and fire a select sum query for each type?

Im not familiar with mysql. But i know, OracleSQL can do stuff like this with insert. 
like `insert into table (col1,col2) (Select * From table)` is like a for-each.

Is my idea possible in mysql?

Comment: Clarify your question what you want to do?

Comment: i want to find out, how many entries there are for each device-type, (sum). If possible by plain sql-query

Comment: like a "count", but for each type of "device"

Comment: Use `group by device` to get each type of device

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to lack a basic level of research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic usecase of the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT   device, COUNT(*) AS num_per_device
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY device
```

Edit:
To answer the followup question by @sgtBear in the comment, you can add the device text by joining this query to another one:

```
SELECT a.device, b.device_text, a.num_per_device
FROM   (SELECT   device, COUNT(*) AS num_per_device
        FROM     my_table
        GROUP BY device) a
JOIN   device_details b ON a.device = b.device
```

Comment: thank you this is the perfect soultion, because devicetype gets displayed to. 
Do you have any idea, how to get "device-text" wich is stored in another table, in the same select? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just try below query:

```
Select Count(Device) 
FROM Table1
Order By Device
Group By Device
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
SELECT Device, COUNT(ID) count_device FROM Table GROUP BY Device
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` clause like this

```
SELECT device, count(device) as total_device
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY device
```

Comment: thank you, works perfectly, just had to change count(ID) to count(device) because i dont need ID...